# entity has many collections of other entities EF 4.2

Tags: entity-framework

I need to model a large number of tables in my domain... I am trying to figure out how to correctly normalize  the following:

I have Address Entity which is Abstract

StreetAddress and POBoxAddress are derived from Address

Many other entities in this domain will need a collection of addresses for instance:

```
Vendor.Addresses
CondoComplex.Addresses
Employee.Addresses
PositionShift.Addresses
Location.Addresses
Guest.Addresses
Property.Addresses
Owner.Addresses
```

etc... many other enities...  So I am confused on how to store these associations in EF ?  As a many to many tph with a discriminator column or am I just missing the forest for the trees and there is an less complex solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance is overused in entity mappings (indeed, it's overused in general, but especially in the case of mapped objects, [which aren't really strongly OO in the first place](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/31/AtTheBoundariesApplicationsAreNotObjectOriented.aspx) and shouldn't generally have behaviors). Most of the time, you should avoid it, as it makes queries and data structures far more complicated. Do you *really* need two different types for `StreetAddress` and `POBoxAddress`? Why? The Post Office won't care.

There needs to be a clear, compelling case for inheritance before you take that complexity into your model. In this case, you not only don't have it, but your question indicates that you have a strong case for not using inheritance here at all.

Comment: I was thinking that the inheritance of the PO Box and Street Address entities was taking things a little too far...  But I just finished a book on domain modeling and normal forms etc... Even if I remove the inheritance and add those properties back into the address entity, I'm still hazy on how EF will setup the relationships... Will it add 10 FK to my Address entity ?  Or will it create 10 different tables to hold this information ?

Comment: If you'll create Address class having all the properties you need (city,street,zip code etc. ) and you will reference it in other classes foreign keys will be assigned to appropriate tables.

Comment: @GregFoote Well, you can design the DB any way you like, and build a corresponding EF model (even with Code First). 10 nullable FKs is certainly one option. Another would be many-to-many mapping tables (e.g., `VendorAddresses`, etc.)

Comment: Regarding EF creating FKs for you, [that's a feature in the new beta](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/29/code-first-migrations-beta-1-released.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the case of complexity of your Address entity aside, if related entities are not going to share Addresses I don't think there's a point in creating many to many relationship. I'm not sure how your abstract Address class looks like, but I would go simply with

```
public List<Address> Addresses {get;set;}
```

in your entities

Comment: So I should add a foreign key for each other entity that wish to have a collection of addresses ?

Comment: or create parent class that all the others would inherit